# matlab font weight is set to normal but appears bold

Tags: matlab, user-interface, fonts

As the title says, it was working fine but now the numbers in the axes appear to be bold, I tried another computer with the same functions and axes appeared normal (set to normal and appeared normal!).

Here's how it looks like:
[image: axes appear bold]

If I change it to light it would be ok but why I'm getting this?

It has nothing to do with the 'centre axes' function I'm using.

**Edit:** Not just the axes, titles and labels as well!

**Edit2:** Everything in MatLab that has a figure like box appears bold! However, when I export a figure it appears normal

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any special Font? Did you remove any default Fonts from your operating system? What OS are you using (looks like Win7?)?

Comment: No i'm not using any special font. OS is windows 7.
Apparently, it's not just MatLab a figure in a pdf document and some text appeared bold as well and when I open it in another computer it appears normal!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you changed the default fonts. Windows uses `Arial` by default. Try the following:

```
set(0, 'defaulttextfontname', 'Arial')
set(0, 'defaultaxesfontname', 'Arial')
```

Comment: Ha! I have been wondering about this 'bug' for ages. I have never knowingly changed the font, but being apparently set to Helvetica at some point resulted in an always bold font. This solved the issue. Thanks!